# Non-zero covariance between degenerate random variable (RV) and non-degenerate RV?

Tags: regression, linear-model, covariance, singular-matrix

Can a degenerate random variable (RV) have a non-zero covariance with a non-degenerate RV (or even degenerate, too)?

My intuition says "no" because that would imply (would it?) that values sampled from the degenerate variable and the non-degenerate have some mutual information, i.e. one can draw conclusions about samples from non-degenerate RV from samples from degenerate RV.

Now, I have to admit that there is a chance that a question is actually about me making mistakes in my algebra, however, I came across a case where it appears so:

I examine two linear models, namely:
$$(1)\ y = X \beta + \epsilon_1+ g \ \ and \ \ (2) \ y = \epsilon_2 + g\\
\epsilon_1 \sim \mathbb{N}(0, \sigma_1^2 I_n), \epsilon_2 \sim \mathbb{N}(0, \sigma_2^2 I_n),\\
g \sim \mathbb{N}(0, \Omega),
$$
where $\Omega$ is some known covariance matrix. Furthermore, $X$ is a square $n \times n$ matrix, i.e. $(1)$ is just a system of linear equations and therefore $\sigma_1 = 0$, so $\epsilon_1$ is degenerate.
Now, I want to study covariance between $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$:
$$cov(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2) = E[(\epsilon_1 - E[\epsilon_1])(\epsilon_2 - E[\epsilon_2])^T] = E[\epsilon_1 \epsilon_2^T] = E[(y- X \beta - g)(y- g)^T] = \\= E[y y^T - X \beta y^T +g g^T] =y y^T - X \beta y^T + \Omega$$
I could argue that as $X \beta$ is numerically $y$, then $y y^T -X \beta y^T = 0$, but there is still $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In relation to your $y$ I suggest you not use the exact same symbol for distinct quantities; a subscript would do
2. However, we can readily answer the title question; if a variable doesn't vary, it can't co-vary (vary with something else). The covariance is definitely 0, the correlation is 0/0 (undefined). The covariance of $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ doesn't involve $\Omega$; fixing your notation problem in 1 will probably help you identify that issue.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the notation part? I don't think I can use distinct symbols for $y$ in (1) and (2) as that would imply that I am trying to explain different quantities with 2 linear models, but I try to explain the same quantity ($y$) with 2 different linear models.

Comment: In that case - assuming you intend both the error terms and the $g$ variable to be independent, since that's how you seem to be calculating with them - at most one of the models can actually be correct; if one is correct the other is untrue and then your calculations with them as random variables don't make sense. [You can *fit* an incorrect model, of course, but that's a different situation]

Comment: Correct /true in what sense? If one model diverges from reality more, I would expect it just having greater σ. The thing is that I am interested in seeing how much common variance there is between their error vectors, i.e. variance that is left unexplained by both model (1) and model (2).

Comment: You keep conflating something fitted to data with a question that is *purely* about random variables (not estimates). You have to stop doing that or the conversation cannot get anywhere. The relationships between *random variables* that you define along with the implied independence of $g$ from the error terms *cannot all be simultaneously as stated*; the mathematical relationships between variables have to all hold if you want to calculate with them as you did. You are defining two y-generating processes but they *cannot* both generate the same distribution for random variable y